# While Resizing webix popup window is getting Closed in internet Explorer Version 11

Tags: javascript, webix

Webix popup window is getting closed when user resize. However
Firefox and Chrome its working fine....

Can anyone tell is it a bug?

[Fiddle Here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/praveensov/1ok1uvd0/3/)